# Comparable interface homework

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

Don't really understand how to implement this in the asked way. here is the question

Create a class Bike that implements the Comparable interface.  You should have the following attributes in the Bike class, color, price, manufacturer, model and rating.  You should perform comparisons based on their prices. Compare them using a tolerance value of 0.0001. Write a main driver to test the program by create bikes where the information is gathered at the console.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Program3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bike b1 = new Bike(300,"red","schwin","mountain crusher",8.6);
    Bike b2 = new Bike(500,"black","cassio","road dominator",12.5);
    Bike b3 = new Bike(200,"blue","rolex","blue diamond",4.3);
    Bike b4 = new Bike(1524500,"silver","military","spy bike",143.2);

    List<Bike> bike = new ArrayList<Bike>();
    bike.add(b1);
    bike.add(b2);
    bike.add(b3);
    bike.add(b4);


    System.out.println(bike);

    Collections.sort(bike);

    System.out.println(bike);



 public class Bike {
private int price;
private String color,brand,model;
private double rating;

public Bike(int price, String color, String brand, String model, double rating) {
    this.price=price;
    this.color=color;
    this.brand=brand;
    this.model=model;
    this.rating=rating;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: was just hoping for some direction was all

Comment: Key word "homework". We don't normally do your homework. Sorry.

Comment: i'm not asking you too, but a big part of figuring out how to work in any industry is getting advice and help from others, basic skill set. There is nothing wrong for asking for direction from people more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: if you don't feel like helping me with understanding the task I have thats fine, but please don't be rude.

Comment: Do you understand this part: `Compare them using a tolerance value of 0.0001.`?

Comment: @user2974899 Advice with a problem you've put work into? Sure. General directions when you're "stuck"? Nope.

Answer (score 3):

The `Comparable` interface contains a single method: `compareTo()`.  This method returns an `int` that describes how one object compares to another.

It is typically used for sorting a collection of objects that this method will be called on, as the value of the returned `int` will tell the caller in which order the two objects belong.

If the `compareTo` method returns a negative, the the object that called the method comes before the object that was used as the argument.  If `compareTo` return a positive, the objected that called the method comes after the object.  If `compareTo` returns 0, then the objects are considered equal and order does not matter.

Your homework is asking you to implement `Comparable` and override the `compareTo` method in order to sort objects of the `Bike` class by their price.  Given `bikeA` with price of two dollars, and `bikeB` with price of three dollars, and `bikeC` with price of three dollars:

```
bikeA.compareTo(bikeB) //should return negative
bikeB.compareTo(bikeA) //should return positive
bikeC.compareTo(bikeB) //should return 0
```

Comment: I think he does not have to perform their sorting. Does he ?

Comment: I don't know.  It doesn't matter whether he has to perform the sorting or not.  I was merely commenting that sorting is the reason the `Comparable` interface exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, the price should be a double, and the rating should be an int. It looks like you got that backwards.

But for implementing the `compareTo`, let's look at what was asked:

> Create a class Bike that implements the Comparable interface.

That's pretty easy: just declare the class as `public class Bike implements Comparable`.

> You should perform comparisons based on their prices.

So? If you are having trouble comprehending the `compareTo` method, here's something to help:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

That's the official description of what this method should do.

> Compare them using a tolerance value of 0.0001.

Here you might need some help. `double` values are imprecise, and must be compared with tolerance for non-exactitude. For example, the expression `0.1 == (0.2 - 0.1)` actually evaluates to `false` because of this. So instead, you can try something like this:

```
(0.1 - (0.2 - 0.1)) < 0.0001
```

Here we just take the difference and see if it is less than a certain amount. That `0.0001` is the tolerance.